# SublimeText 3 Package installing errot

Tags: sublimetext3

I installed SublimeText 3 (V 3207) on Windows today and Cannot get package installation working. It gave me errors in installing Package Control as well but looking at web I was able to clone the GIT repo to get it installed. But still the Install Package returns with  502 error.

```
Package Control: Error downloading channel. HTTP error 502 downloading https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json
```

https://packagecontrol.io cannot be reached directly either. Is there an alternate way to download packages?

Answer (score 0):

Package Control was [down due to a migration](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/package-control-migration/) being carried out by the author. Last year there was a failure on the machine that hosts the site and it was migrated to a backup machine, but the IP address changed and that IP address was one that is blocked in China.

The migration that was done last night moves the site to a new VM that uses the same IP address that it had back before that outage, which restores the ability of China to see and install packages.

The migration is now complete and everything should be working correctly. There is no official backup site, though.